# Get numbers before specific string

Tags: regex, r, substring

I'm trying to get a 1 or 2 digit number before a specific string.  I'm parsing from json and I get the following string

```
Batted ball speed <b>107 mph</b>; distance of <b>399 feet</b> at an angle of <b>5 degrees</b>.
Batted ball speed <b>92 mph</b>; distance of <b>210 feet</b> at an angle of <b>25 degrees</b>.
```

Below is the code that works for 2 digit degrees.  If I drop one of the [0-9] then I can obviously get the 1 digit to work.

```
Degrees = substr(feedplay_dat$items$data$description_tracking, regexpr("<b>[0-9]+[0-9] degrees", feedplay_dat$items$data$description_tracking), regexpr("[0-9] degrees", feedplay_dat$items$data$description_tracking))
```

My question is how do I change the code to get both degree numbers whether they are 1 or 2 digits, or maybe even 3 digits?

***EDIT***

The possible duplicate did not answer my question because the + means it has to match it at least one time.  I did however get the answer from that post and from Franks suggestion.  I ended up using the * for the zero or more times and that works perfectly.

Comment: Can't you just do `\d+ degrees` (or swap the `\d` with `[0-9]` if `r` doesn't take that)? The `+` quantifier is one ore more of the previous character/group.

Comment: Check out the "quantifiers" part of the `?regex` doc

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, not update the question.